# Why is the probabilty of an event that constrains one coordinate of a Brownian motion zero?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am struggling with a detail related to the trajectories of stochastic processes. I am working with Brownian motion, but technically any continuous stochastic process would make no difference. However, to have a specific model in mind, let's say that it is a Brownian motion starting at $0 $ and the let $P^0 $ be the probability measure associated with a Brownian motion that starts at $0. $

I am working with the canonical stochastic process so that the space is $\Omega \doteq C[0, \infty) $ and each $\omega \in \Omega $ is a continuous function on $[0, \infty). $  In a paper I found a statement that says that:
$$ P^0[\{\omega \in \Omega: \omega(1/n) = 0\}] = 0. $$

If this fact is true, then one can prove that the trajectories or Brownian motion that are constant on the interval $[0, \epsilon] $ for some $\epsilon > 0 $ have probability zero as well.

I cannot convince myself that constraining a single coordinate of the process causes it to have probability zero. Could anyone help me understand why it is so? I believe it is as I saw this fact mentioned directly or indirectly in more than one place.

Thank you

Comment: Is it surprising to you that the probability that an angle chosen uniformly from the interval $[0, 2\pi)$ has probability zero of being either (say) $\pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$?

Comment: How do you define the set $\{\omega \in \Omega: \omega(1/n)\}$?  The set of all $\omega\in\Omega$ such that...?  (It's possible it's a typo or a notation I've never encountered)

Comment: @BrianMoehring  $\Omega $ is the space of continuous functions on $[0, \infty) $ so each $\omega $ is a continuous function and $\omega(1/n) = 0. $

Comment: @BrianTung  An angle I have no problem to see since  I am just looking at 1 value out of (uncountable) many. But in the case of the space $C[0, \infty) $ there are infinite continuous trajectories that cross the x-axis at $1/n. $ What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share the citation on this paper?

Comment: @ The paper is not published. But there are examples where this  type  of argument is used. For instance Medvegyev, Stochastic Integration Theory has an example (Example 1:13) where a similar argument is used. I recall also my old graduate school textbook Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus (2nd Edition) Problem 2.7:14 for which I have the solution where this type of argument is used. I get the entire argument, I just fail to see zero probability. What I reported was the line used (word for word) except the sentence began by "Obviously"

Comment: To clarify, I would rather write that set $\{\omega \in \Omega: \omega(1/n)=0\}$, so it's the lack of the $=0$ I was questioning.  In any case, it might be helpful to remember that for a fixed point $a>0$, $P^0[\{\omega \in \Omega: \omega(a)\leq x\}]$ is the cumulative distribution function of a normal random variable with variance $a$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring   Thank you. Silly me... that is what I was missing.. I got so caught up on the $C[0, \infty) $ thing that I forgot that the probability is actually on the point... I am embarassed...